# How to deploy a truffle built Dapp

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, dapps

I've completed my truffle Dapp, the contracts are deployed to the Ropsten test network and my web code talks nicely to them, it works great from http://localhost:8080/ when I do an `npm run dev`.

I now want to put it onto a live webserver, still connected to Ropsten, no code changes, just the built code that is running on localhost in my browser.

How do I do a build for deployment to a webserver?

Comment: Did you do it? If yes, can you please answer the question? @kris

Comment: `npm run build`
Builds the Dapp into /build

Answer (score 0):

## `$ npm run build`

Builds the Dapp into /build
You may need to then also copy over static resources, like /images

*(Thanks to : http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-testing-frontend-app-truffle-3)*

Comment: @Down-voters - please provide a better answer if you have one